# How to use Math.Round()?

Tags: vb.net

Today I wonder what Math method is used in vb.net's Math.Round(). I have code below and I don't know why the program gives the same result. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
 Module Module1    
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Math.Round" & Math.Round(23.5))
        Console.WriteLine("Math.Round" & Math.Round(24.5))
        Console.ReadLine()    
    End Sub    
 End Module
```

Comment: If you want to make sure that .5 rounds up, you can use a Floor trick: `Math.Floor(x + 0.5)` will always round `x` to the nearest integer.

Comment: @CompuChip or you could use [the `Math.Round` overload that allows you to specify a `MidpointRounding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274.aspx), to make it obvious what you mean.

Comment: Usually the program give the same result. I don't know how it going on?

Answer (score 2):

**Midpoint values are rounded to the nearest even number.**

Change `24.5` to `24.51`

```
    Console.WriteLine("Math.Round" & Math.Round(23.5))
    Console.WriteLine("Math.Round" & Math.Round(24.51))
```

and see the difference in results

> Math.Round24
>
> Math.Round25

Comment: Isn't that what the answer explains?

Comment: @un-lucky : Kindly read the question and then the answer carefully.

Comment: Why Math.Round(23.5) is not gave result 23 but result gave 24?

Comment: when the input is midpoint, for example, 23.5, it could be rounded off to either 23 or 24. precedence goes to even number. so result will be 24.hope that answers!

Answer (score 0):

As the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains the Math.Round Method:

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Decimal
>
> The integer nearest parameter d. If the fractional component of d is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, the even number is returned. Note that this method returns a Decimal instead of an integral type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.Round for any value. Here example is only for one values

```
Dim Value1 as string = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(24.51), 2)
Console.WriteLine("Math.Round" & Value1)
```

**Result:**
25.00